# How to use the API of ZKTeco devices in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zkteco

The process of adding a user to the device does not work in Laravel
Those who can help provide the solution from the beginning of the process

this is my code...

```
      
      use maliklibs\Zkteco\Lib\ZKTeco;   
      $zk = new ZKTeco('192.168.100.222',4370);
      $zk->connect();
      $zk->enableDevice();
      $zk->setUser(1, '211', 'Carl', '5555', Util::LEVEL_USER, '0007909321');
      $zk->disableDevice();
```

This is the package that I use
https://github.com/sketchtechnologies1/zkteco/tree/main

Comment: Missing semicolon! `$zk->setUser(1, '211', 'Carl', '5555', Util::LEVEL_USER, '0007909321');`

Answer (score 0):

First check if connection is OK, use `ineger` in the number arguments. Don't try `1` as unique ID, It's maybe admin or something try `10`.

**Note: Read the docs**

> You have to call `disableDevice()` before read/write any info of Device.

> You have to call `enableDevice()` after read/write any info of Device.

So he working code should be:

```php
$result = $err = "";
if($err = $zk->connect()){
    echo "OK Connect\n";
    $zk->disableDevice();
    echo "OK Enable\n";
    $result = $zk->setUser(10, 211, 'Carl', '5555', Util::LEVEL_USER, '0007909321');
    $zk->enableDevice();
} else {
    echo "Connect Error: $err\n"
}
var_dump($result); // to check if there is an error
```

Comment: my result is    OK Connect string(0) ""

Comment: @RanemSamer let me know if it didn't work.

Comment: it's didn't work

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: Did you check the updated answer??? What's the output?

Comment: the output is : OK Connect Enable Error: string(0) ""

Comment: Check the updated code again please.

Comment: here seems to be a problem in disable and enable function ..can you help me

Comment: What's the output of new code? If the device is turned on and fully connected

Comment: How did you check? it is setting the user number 10! Did you check the user number 10 on device?

Answer (score 0):

This could help:

```
$zk = new ZKTeco('192.168.100.222', 4370);
$zk->connect();
$zk->enableDevice();

$user_id = 1;
$user_name = 'Carl';
$password = '5555';
$level = Util::LEVEL_USER;
$card_number = '0007909321';

$result = $zk->setUser($user_id, '', $user_name, $password, $level, $card_number);
if ($result) {
    echo 'User added successfully';
} else {
    echo 'Failed to add user';
}

$zk->disableDevice();

$zk->disconnect();
```

Comment: the output is :Failed to add user

Comment: There seems to be a problem in disable and enable function ..can you help me

Comment: Can you show me Error message?